# Write inside a container with an image covering the entire background

Tags: html, css

I have this code in codepen, I have created a nested container, in one I am loading an image where it takes the full background and it's completely responsive, now what I want is to simply be able to use another container and write text in it and place it somewhere on this image. What happens is that everything I add comes under the full cover image. Now I know all about using css to create a background image but those are not really fully responsive. I want to know if there's a possibility to use the nested columns.
The code is here: http://codepen.io/spacepirate/pen/LNyxXM

```
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:100px">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9ayqwlborr31kd/Earth.jpg?raw=1" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
    Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> write text in it and place it somewhere on this image

If you want to place it somewhere, use then `position:absolute;` for your text and keep your image like you have now.

Or try this:

`<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9ayqwlborr31kd/Earth.jpg?raw=1" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute;width:100%;">`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hn5dyu8d/)**

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Using `padding-bottom:100%;` is actually not nessecary ;).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the background-image tag?

background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9ayqwlborr31kd/Earth.jpg?raw=1");

Comment: Because background-image is not as fully responsive as putting an image inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="row parent-block" style="padding-top:100px">
      <div class="col-xs-12 child-image-block">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9ayqwlborr31kd/Earth.jpg?raw=1" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
        <div class="row child-content-block">
           <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
             Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
              Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent-block { position:relative;}
.child-image-block { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; z-index:1;}
.child-image-block img { width:100%;}
.child-content-block {position:relative; z-index:3;}
```